# Extracted float values are stored in a list of lists instead of a list of values

Tags: python, list, floating-point

I am doing an exercise for finding all the float point values in a text file and computing the average . 
I have managed to extract all the necessary values but they are being stored in a list of lists and I don't know how extract them as floats in order to do the calculations .
Here is my code :

```
import re
fname = input("Enter file name: ")
fhandle = open(fname)
x = []

count = 0
for line in fhandle:
   if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue

   s = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", line)
   x.append(s)
count = count + 1



print(x)

print("Done")
```

and this is the output of x :

```
[['0.8475'], ['0.6178'], ['0.6961'], ['0.7565'], ['0.7626'], ['0.7556'], ['0.7002'], ['0.7615'], ['0.7601'], ['0.7605'], ['0.6959'], ['0.7606'], ['0.7559'], ['0.7605'], ['0.6932'], ['0.7558'], ['0.6526'], ['0.6948'], ['0.6528'], ['0.7002'], ['0.7554'], ['0.6956'], ['0.6959'], ['0.7556'], ['0.9846'], ['0.8509'], ['0.9907']]
Done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `x` a flat list of floats from the start:

```
# ...
for line in fhandle:
    # ...
    s = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", line)
    x.extend(map(float, s))
```

Note that `re.findall` returns a list, so we extend `x` by it while applying `float` to all the strings in it.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed . Thank you . I wasn't aware that ``` re.findall ``` returns a list . But happy that I found out .